# What is the best scenario in this case?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have two tables: **Employee** and **Training**, Employee table has two columns: **ID** (numeric) and **Name** (text).
Training table also has two columns:  **No** (numeric) and **TrainingName** (text).

My boss asked me the following:
Some **trainingName** can be classified by “group name” (group name can dynamically be added by user input) and one traininName can be classified in one group, no group or more than one group. Each employee can be under one group or no group.(can not be under two or more groups).
I am confused in how to manage that? Do I need to create another table or modify the existing tables?
I am using PostgreSQL9.2.

Comment: It sounds like you'd need to add more tables for this.  Perhaps a `TrainingGroup` table and two relationship tables for the many-to-many relationships between `TrainingGroup` and the two existing tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add two more tables: "groups", and "groups_trainings".

This will be your resulting Database-Layout:

```
employees:
    id
    name
    group (foreign key to groups.id; can be null)

trainings:
    id
    trainingName

groups:
    id
    groupName

groups_trainings
    id
    trainingID (foreign key to trainings.id)
    groupID (foreign key to groups.id)
```

You need the last table, to map n groups to n trainings.

The layout says the following:

- Each empoyee belongs to one group, or no group (employees.group is null)
- Each group can contain 0 or more trainings.
- Each training can be part of 0 or more groups